# Getting Error message "Error in plugin [logsMetric]: Access is denied." in Cloudwatch Agent Logs

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs, amazon-cloudwatch-metrics

Getting Error message

> "Error in plugin [logsMetric]: Access is denied."

I am using EC2 windows . I have installed the **cloudwatch** agent and created the *config.json* .

I started the agent. The windows logs are being written to **cloudwatch** but the application logs are not. I am getting

> [logsMetric]: Access is denied

in the CLoudwatchagent logs
I have application logs  under

*C:\Apachelogs* , *C:\MongoLogs*

Which is the application logs are not being written.
I have also attached the following policies to the instance
**CloudWatchAgentAdminPolicy** and
**AmazonSSMManagedInstanceCore**

config.json:

```
{
"logs": {
    "logs_collected": {
        "files": {
            "collect_list": [
                {
                    "file_path": "C:\\ApacheLogs",
                    "log_group_name": "ApacheLogs",
                    "log_stream_name": "{instance_id}"
                },
                {
                    "file_path": "C:\\Platformlog",
                    "log_group_name": "Platformlog",
                    "log_stream_name": "{instance_id}"
                },
                {
                    "file_path": "C:\\Enrichmentlog",
                    "log_group_name": "Enrichmentlog",
                    "log_stream_name": "{instance_id}"
                },
                {
                    "file_path": "C:\\Mongolog",
                    "log_group_name": "Mongolog",
                    "log_stream_name": "{instance_id}"
                }
            ]
        },
        "windows_events": {
            "collect_list": [
                {
                    "event_format": "xml",
                    "event_levels": [
                        "VERBOSE",
                        "INFORMATION",
                        "WARNING",
                        "ERROR",
                        "CRITICAL"
                    ],
                    "event_name": "System",
                    "log_group_name": "System",
                    "log_stream_name": "{instance_id}"
                },
                {
                    "event_format": "xml",
                    "event_levels": [
                        "VERBOSE",
                        "INFORMATION",
                        "WARNING",
                        "ERROR",
                        "CRITICAL"
                    ],
                    "event_name": "System",
                    "log_group_name": "System",
                    "log_stream_name": "{instance_id}"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
},
"metrics": {
    "append_dimensions": {
        "AutoScalingGroupName": "${aws:AutoScalingGroupName}",
        "ImageId": "${aws:ImageId}",
        "InstanceId": "${aws:InstanceId}",
        "InstanceType": "${aws:InstanceType}"
    },
    "metrics_collected": {
        "Memory": {
            "measurement": [
                "% Committed Bytes In Use"
            ],
            "metrics_collection_interval": 60
        },
        "Paging File": {
            "measurement": [
                "% Usage"
            ],
            "metrics_collection_interval": 60,
            "resources": [
                "*"
            ]
        },
        "statsd": {
            "metrics_aggregation_interval": 60,
            "metrics_collection_interval": 60,
            "service_address": ":8125"
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution I found,

We need to specify file path or file pattern which we need to collect from folder.
earlier i have just mentioned path up to the folder.

Earlier :

> "file_path": "C:\ApacheLogs",

Working Solution :

> "file_path": "C:\ApacheLogs\*.logs"